# Carbonyl and thiocarbonyl 13C NMR

Tags: orbitals, nmr-spectroscopy

According to [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237864453_A_solid-state_13C_NMR_and_theoretical_investigation_of_carbonyl_and_thiocarbonyl_carbon_chemical_shift_tensors), the deshielding effect of C=S group is specifically due to the delta(11), which is the least shielded component. However, the conclusion tells me that this component is governed by two transitions: σ → π(antibonding) and π → σ(antibonding) transition.

The thing confuses me is that, as the excited energy magnitude is smaller, the paramagnetic shielding should be more negative, also means the nucleus is more deshielded. When it comes to normal thought of C=O and C=S transtion, the n → π(antibonding) is lower in energy than σ → π(antibonding) and π → σ(antibonding). So why carbon on C=S has greater chemical shift than that of C=O?